# Ursina, poor positioning of textures on a complex blender model

Tags: python, blender, texture-mapping, uv-mapping, ursina

I have been trying for some days to make a 3D character that I can display with **Ursina** in Python. However, when I display my character with the appropriate texture, the r**esult obtained on Ursina is totally different from that on Blender**. Maybe the problem is that I gave my character a special position on Ursina with an **armature**. I did tests to find the problem by doing a **UV Editing** **with unwrapped or a without** and changing some data of the Smart UV Project, but in any case, the result remains different compared to Blender. I show you the difference between Blender and Ursina:
[image: Blender]
[image: Ursina without unwrap]

So if anyone has an idea to help me, that would be nice. :)
Thanks in advance.
Jules.

Comment: I noticed there is also problems in the model on Ursina because there is some that become transparent when I change my view.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually export the .blend to .obj to use them in ursina. ursina can tell blender to do that automatically. Just `model='name_of_model_without_extension'`. Try using that.

If you still want to export manually, remember to triangulate the mesh on export.

Comment: There was in fact a problem of front-facing. We had to add: flipped_faces=False, double_sided=True